# How to make Snakemake recognize Globus remote files using Globus CLI?

Tags: hpc, snakemake, globus-toolkit

I am working in a high performance computing grid environment, where large-scale data transfers are done via [Globus](https://www.globus.org). I would like to use Snakemake to pull data from a Globus path, process the data, and then push the processed data to a different Globus path. Globus has a [command-line interface](https://docs.globus.org/cli/).

Pulling the data is no problem, for I'd just create a rule that would run `globus transfer` to create the requisite local file. But for pushing the data back to Globus, I think I'll need a rule that can "see" that the file is missing at the remote location, and then work backwards to determine what needs to happen to create the file.

I could create local "proxy" files that represent the remote files. For example I could make a rule for creating 'processed_data_1234.tar.gz' output files in a directory. These files would just be created using `touch` (thus empty), and the same rule will run `globus transfer` to push the files remotely. But then there's the overhead of making sure that the proxy files don't get out of sync with the real Globus-hosted files.

Is there a more elegant way to do this akin to the [Remote File](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html) capability? Is it difficult to add a Globus CLI support for Snakemake? Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it help to create a utility function that would generate a list of all desired files and compare it against the list of files available on globus? Something like this (pseudocode):

```py
def return_needed_files():
    list_needed_files = [] # either hard-coded or specified with some logic
    list_available = [] # as appropriate, e.g. using globus ls
    return [i for i in list_needed_files if i not in list_available]

# include all the needed files in the all rule
rule all:
    input: return_needed_files
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to do so short of extending Snakemake. Thanks!